# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Private keys must be instance of RSAPrivate(Crt)Key or have PKCS#8 encoding

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, private-key, pkcs#11, e-token

I have created a sample web service to digitally sign a document using etoken. It is creating the Signature file for the first time.But when I am trying to run the web service again it throwing me the following error.Can anyone update regarding this?

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Private keys must be instance of
>   RSAPrivate(Crt)Key or have PKCS#8 encoding    at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.translatePrivateKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineTranslateKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:191)
>     at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.toRSAKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:111)
>     at
>   sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineInitSign(RSASignature.java:106)
>     at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineInitSign(RSASignature.java:99)
>     at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1152)

Comment: It would be better if you posted the code that threw this error.

Comment: Quite likely you have to add a provider argument when you request the signature, a provider argument matching the provider of your private key.